# Simplify this jQuery using .hasClass and .bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify this code.

Basically, #griffyindor has the 'active' class by default when the page loads. When it has the 'active' class, I want all the other houses (slytherin, ravenclaw, and hufflepuff) to show. However, at some point it may lose its 'active' class when I click on something else. But when I click back to it, I want the initial behavior again.

Is there a way to simplify what's below to check when gryffindor has the 'active' class OR when gryffindor is clicked on (so that it gets the 'active' class)?

```
 $(function() {
    var gryffindor = $('#gryffindor');
    if (gryffindor.hasClass('active')) {
            console.log('show all the houses');
            $('#slytherin, #ravenclaw, #hufflepuff').show();
    }
    gryffindor.bind('click', function() {
        if (gryffindor.hasClass('active')) {
            console.log('all is active');
            $('#slytherin, #ravenclaw, #hufflepuff').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: And what is `label_all` supposed to be? Where is that defined?

Comment: Oh, oops. That was supposed to be 'gryffindor'.

Comment: (Just fixed. The code is working; just wondering if there's a way to make it better.)

Comment: This would be better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Can you reproduce it in its working state? Either with Stack Snippets (here in your question, click the icon following the image (the one that has the pencil on it)) or over on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). I'm not sure I understand what the problem is, or what it's meant to do, other than show all the other houses when gryffindor gets the 'active' class.

Comment: You can simplify it by removing the first if-clause. You said it always starts out with class `active` anyway, so why bother to check it? Also, use `on.` instead of `.bind`. (And I wouldn't store the element into a variable, but I guess that would be ever so slightly faster, but then again it would consume more memory for the extra var

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(function() {
    $('#gryffindor').on('click', function(e) {
        this.toggleClass('active');
        if (this.hasClass('active'); {
            $('#slytherin, #ravenclaw, #hufflepuff').show();
        } /*else {
            $('#slytherin, #ravenclaw, #hufflepuff').hide();
        }*/ //Not sure if this is part of what you want
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that `.bind` maps to `.on` in current version of jQuery. `.toggleClass` will add or remove class based on the index of your click (defaults to 0).

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(function() {

   var $gryffindor = $('#gryffindor');

   $('#slytherin, #ravenclaw, #hufflepuff').hide();

   $gryffindor.on('click', function(e) {

     $(this).toggleClass('active');

     if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
       $('#slytherin, #ravenclaw, #hufflepuff').show();
     } else {
       $('#slytherin, #ravenclaw, #hufflepuff').hide();
     }


   });


 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="gryffindor">Griffindor</button>

<div id="slytherin">slytherin</div>
<div id="ravenclaw">ravenclaw</div>
<div id="hufflepuff">hufflepuff</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var houses = $("#houses li");
$(document).on('click', '#houses li', function(){
    var activate_house = this;
    $(houses).each(function (index) {
        var house = this
        $(house).removeClass('active');
        $(house).removeClass('show');
    });
    $(activate_house).addClass('active');
    showHouses();
});

function showHouses(){
    $(houses).each(function (index) {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
           $(this).addClass('show');
        }
    });
}
showHouses();
```

```css
.show{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="houses">
        <li class="active" id="gryffindor">gryffindor</li>
        <li  id="slytherin">slytherin</li>
        <li  id="ravenclaw">ravenclaw</li>
        <li  id="hufflepuff">hufflepuff</li>
</ul>
```

not minify your code but simplify the reading and adds semantic, see [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avenda/7p34ak8d/)